# Introduction Javascript - syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm trying to build a rock , paper, scissors game with javascript.
Here is my code :

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = ["r", "p", "s"];
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
            console.log("event=", event);
            var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();

            console.log(userGuess);

            var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

            console.log(computerGuess);

            if ((userGuess === "r") && (computerGuess === "p")) {
                alert("Paper smothers rock - You lose.");
            } else
            if ((userGuess === "r") && (computerGuess === "s")) {
                alert("Rock smashes scissors - You win!")
            } else
            if ((userGuess === "p") && (computerGuess === "s")) {
                alert("Scissors cuts paper to pieces - You lose.");
            } else if ((userGuess === "p") && (computerGuess === "r")) {
                alert("Paper smothers rock - You win");
            } else if ((userGuess === "s") && (computerGuess === "r")) {
                alert("Rock smashes scissors - You lose.");

            } else if ((userGuess === "s") && (computerGuess === "p")) {
                alert("Scissors cuts paper to pieces - You win!")
            } else if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
                alert("You tie!");
            }
            
    </script>
```

when in console, I keep getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
I've tried so many things it's embarrassing. Again, please excuse my utter noobness.  Any help would be appreciated.r

Comment: Looks to me like you haven't closed your `onkeyup` function. Add `};` to the end of your file.

Comment: More specifically- add `};`  on the line just before `</script>`

Comment: Thanks, man.  So many brackets and parenthesis and semis lol

Comment: Consider using a linter to help with syntax issues and other common problems. They'll often give you more helpful messages. For example, http://jshint.com/ will tell you `2  Unmatched '{'`, where `2` is the line number that starts the unbalanced set of braces.

Comment: @squint  thank you!  I'm in a bootcamp, super fast-paced, pretty much all self-taught.  so thanks for the link to avoid future questions of such simplicity.

Comment: You're welcome. And questions are fine, but the tools are usually faster.

Comment: totally prefer the tools!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onkeyup function should be closed.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var options = ["r", "p", "s"];

document.onkeyup = function(event){
//Your code here
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var options = ["r", "p", "s"];
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
            console.log("event=", event);
            var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();

            console.log(userGuess);

            var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

            console.log(computerGuess);

            if ((userGuess === "r") && (computerGuess === "p")) {
                alert("Paper smothers rock - You lose.");
            } else
            if ((userGuess === "r") && (computerGuess === "s")) {
                alert("Rock smashes scissors - You win!")
            } else
            if ((userGuess === "p") && (computerGuess === "s")) {
                alert("Scissors cuts paper to pieces - You lose.");
            } else if ((userGuess === "p") && (computerGuess === "r")) {
                alert("Paper smothers rock - You win");
            } else if ((userGuess === "s") && (computerGuess === "r")) {
                alert("Rock smashes scissors - You lose.");

            } else if ((userGuess === "s") && (computerGuess === "p")) {
                alert("Scissors cuts paper to pieces - You win!")
            } else if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
                alert("You tie!");
            }
         }
```

it looks like you're missing a closing bracket on your onkeyup function

Comment: Your snippet is throwing an error.  If you're going to include the script tags, place the code in the HTML section of the snippet editor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - still learning statckoverflow as well

Comment: thanks, didn't catch that.  I just copied the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing the clossing for the onKeyUp, if you copy the hole script the the browser console and add that missing }. you will see that the page starts showing the alerts

Comment: Thank you- the minor issue has been fixed - the little syntax errors are ALWAYS what seems to be awry. At least I know what to work on lol.